# How to Get-WMIObject Win32_PnPEntity | where {$_.Name -like "USB Serial Port*"} by Model (label) of Unspecified Device

Tags: powershell, serial-port, wmi

With PowerShell I ask the following:

```
Get-WMIObject Win32_PnPEntity | where {$_.Name -like "USB Serial Port*"} |
    Format-Table Name, Description, Manufacturer
```

The output brings me:

```
Name         : USB Serial Port (COM15)
Description  : USB Serial Port
Manufacturer : FTDI

Name         : USB Serial Port (COM10)
Description  : USB Serial Port
Manufacturer : FTDI
```

So I get two results with the difference in brackets. What I am looking for is to get COMxx but by the Model(label) displayed in (Control Panel - Devices and Printers - Unspecified - an item Properties) to get exactly what I need, means COM number of the device. Please see the ScreeShot for example. Note that the label is hidden for security reason.

[image: device info as shown in control panel]

Is anyone of you who knows a way to solution? I will be appreciated for your help.

Comment: Grab WMI Explorer it might point you in the right direction, right now you have the port (USB Serial), what you need is the device connected to it which I think will come from Win32_PnPDevice. This should then point you at a third element. Something like Win32_printer if its a printer. If it is just Com ports you are dealing with, you can drop Win32_PNPEntity and use Win32_SerialPort, this should give you enougth information to for-each into PnPDevice and from there to the actual devices end Win32_ element.

Comment: Bob007 I've been trying them already. There is no positive effect. If I ask for the whole list of Win32_PnPDevice there is nothing what can help me or I don't know that it can. Anyway, the list includes paths where I can find something like `\root\\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID=...` but on the output there is no my device id which starts like `\root\cimv2:Win32_PnPEntity.DeviceID="FTDIBUS`. If comes to Win32_SerialPort it list my serial ports except for the ones assigned to unspecified devices.

Comment: `Win32_USBControllerDevice' brings me my device id but nothing else I could be interesting of

Answer (score 0):

I don't have anything with direct attached printers at hand right now to confirm with but the property your looking for should be either caption or description.  you can view all of the properties available on the object by piping it to `Get-Member` or just to `Format-List` to see what everything is evaluating to.   More info on the properties available to that class is available [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394353(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: If I `use Get-WMIObject Win32_PnPEntity | where {$_.Name -like "USB Serial Port*"} `

Comment: yes, pipe the results of that to `get-member` and you'll see the available properties, if you use `Format-List` you can see what they evaluate to and select the one that matches up with what you need.

Comment: Thanks Mike. Caption equals Description: `USB Serial Port (COM15)`. If I ask for whole list there is nothing about the Model(label) I'm looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like issue has been frozen

https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/82a8a4bd-6db3-4fe7-9e5e-915498eb6ba0/how-to-getwmiobject-win32pnpentity-where-name-like-usb-serial-port-by-model-label-of?forum=winserverpowershell